# VSCode: Debug > Add Configuration, nothing happens

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using Visual Studio Code v 1.32.3 on Windows 10, when I navigate to Debug > Add Configuration, nothing happens. No errors or other messages, nothing appears to be written to the workspace folder, no errors in Event Viewer, so far just nothing.

I am somewhat new to VSCode so please don't discount that this might be a newbie error. Potentially notable is that the project is a Cordova project, I have created a Workspace (and confirmed that I am using it and not just opening the folder).

What I have checked so far:

- Verifying that nothing is actively trying to build or otherwise access that folder. PhoneGap Desktop is stopped and no emulators running.
- Restarted PC
- Reinstalled the Cordova Tools plugin

Interestingly if I open a new instance of VS Code and before opening any file or folder I go back to Debug > Add Configuration I will get a message "Please first open a folder in order to do advanced debug configura..." So this indicates that there may be a problem with my workspace or directory but I haven't found it yet.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Edit 1:

Version of Cordova Tools is 1.8.0.

I've since tried adding my own launch.json to the .vscode directory. Contents:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Run android on device|emulator",
        "type": "cordova",
        "request": "launch",
        "platform": "android",
        "target": "device|emulator",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    ]
}
```

Notable is that in the bottom right corner of the window a "Add Configuration" button appears while I am viewing launch.json and it does appear to work correctly, prompting me with snippets to add.

None of these impact my ability to debug unfortunately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright I think I have this working. Steps:

- I deleted the launch.json added in my edit. (Effectively now no launch.json file again)
- Navigate to Debug > Start Debugging
- Ignore the error dialog that appears
- VSCode will create a launch.json and display the debug menu

From here it looks like I'm back on track.

Answer (score 1):

For me when I press **Add Configuration** from the *dropdown on the upper left* it does nothing, I keep pressing up and down in and out of places and suddently it works... then it does not again...

However I found a **blue button on the lower right of the screen** that works more consistently, I'm uncertain if it is the same issue or that button doesn't work for you either but this was my own experience.

[image]

Comment: That was a solution for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Check VS Code **OUTPUT** window. When VS Code is downloading some launcher packages like *.NET Core Launch*, Debugging process may be affected.
After downloading packages are completed check it again.

Answer (score 1):

ctrl + shift + P then enter "reload window" works for me

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the latest version of VS Code? I had the same problem and I fixed it by updating to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

One silly mistake that may lead to this problem is and that I did was to debug when in a non executable file, so be sure to be in that file which is executable. In my case it was a **.cpp** file where I should've been but I was in one of the header file **.h** that I created while debugging.

Answer (score -1):

You should delete **.vscode** folder and run again debugger extension.
This will generate a new .vscode folder with a launch.json file in.

Comment: That would wipe out all extensions and customization, right?